# Пересечение множеств Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, множества

Даны два списка чисел. Нужно вывести числа, которые входят как в первый, так и во второй список.
Ввожу списки:

```
a = list(map(int, input().split()))
b = list(map(int, input().split()))
```

Пытаюсь вывести список элементов пересечения множеств:

```
print(list(set(a) & set(b)))
```

и для

```
7 8 9 7 8 9
4 5 4 5
```

получаю на выходе:

```
[]
```

а хотелось бы

```
[4, 5, 7, 8, 9]
```

Comment: "Как в первый, так и во второй" означает, что число есть и в первом списке, и во втором. Вы же ищете числа, которые есть хотя бы в одном списке. Это называется сумма множеств, а не пересечение.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ваше определение `"числа, которые входят как в первый, так и во второй список"` - можно воспринять двояко: как объединение и как пересечение множеств.

Судя по ожидаемому результату, вам нужно объединение (`union`) множеств:

```
In [113]: print(list(set(a) | set(b)))
[4, 5, 7, 8, 9]
```

или

```
In [114]: print(list(set(a).union(set(b))))
[4, 5, 7, 8, 9]
```